# Why does flatten on nested Iterator not compile and why do I need type ascription?

Tags: scala, type-inference, ascription

```
(new Iterator[List[Int]] {
  def hasNext: Boolean = ???
  def next(): List[Int] = ???
}).flatten
```

gives error:

```
value flatten is not a member of Iterator[List[Int]]
[error] possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value flatten'?
[error]     }.flatten
[error]       ^
[error] one error found
```

But

```
(new Iterator[List[Int]] {
  def hasNext: Boolean = ???
  def next(): List[Int] = ???
}: Iterator[List[Int]]).flatten
```

works.  Also storing the iterator in a val works.

Scala version: 2.11.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this issue was addressed by [Include the parts of a compound/refinement type in implicit scope. #5867](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5867). The problem was companion to anonymous classes used to not qualify for implicit search

> I think aaf9198#diff-7c03397456d3b987549fd039d6b639c6R516 was the
>   first to exclude refinement/anon classes from contributing to
>   companion implicits. @odersky Can you remember the motivation?

Here is a minimal reproduction

```
trait A {
  def foo(): Int
}
class B {
  def bar(): String = "woohoo"
}
object A {
  implicit def aToB(a: A): B = new B
}

(new A {
  override def foo(): Int = 42
}).bar()

// Error: 
// value bar is not a member of A$A12.this.A 
// possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value bar'? }).bar();
```

Therefore since in 2.11 and 2.12 `flatten` on `Iterator` was provided as an extension method via [flattenTraversableOnce](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.TraversableOnce$@flattenTraversableOnce[A,CC[_]](travs:scala.collection.TraversableOnce[CC[A]])(implicitev:CC[A]=%3Escala.collection.TraversableOnce[A]):scala.collection.TraversableOnce.FlattenOps[A]) the issue would manifest for anonymous `Iterator` class.

---

*<sup>The following is my answer prior to the edit above:</sup>*

It seems to have something to do with implicit resolution in both 2.11 and 2.12. If you explicitly import `flatten` as an extension method via

```
import scala.collection.TraversableOnce.flattenTraversableOnce
```

then it seems to work. The issue seems to be fixed since 2.13.0-M3 where typer phase gives

```
collection.this.TraversableOnce.flattenTraversableOnce[Int, List]({
  final class $anon extends AnyRef with Iterator[List[Int]] {
    def <init>(): <$anon: Iterator[List[Int]]> = {
      $anon.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    def hasNext: Boolean = scala.Predef.???;
    def next(): List[Int] = scala.Predef.???
  };
  new $anon()
})(scala.Predef.$conforms[List[Int]]).flatten
```

whilst in 2.13.0 release `flatten` no longer seem to be provided via extension method

```
{
  final class $anon extends AnyRef with Iterator[List[Int]] {
    def <init>(): <$anon: Iterator[List[Int]]> = {
      $anon.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    def hasNext: Boolean = scala.Predef.???;
    def next(): List[Int] = scala.Predef.???
  };
  new $anon()
}.flatten[Int](scala.Predef.$conforms[List[Int]])
```

The above expansion seems to be explained by [SLS 6.4 Designators](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#designators)

> .  is typed as if it was { val  = ; . }

Answer (score 1):

I think it tries to parse this:

```scala
new Iterator[List[Int]] {
      def hasNext: Boolean = ???
      def next(): List[Int] = ???
    }.flatten
```

as this

```scala
new Iterator[List[Int]] ( {
      def hasNext: Boolean = ???
      def next(): List[Int] = ???
    }.flatten )
```

Notice where I added the parentheses `()`.

Comment: Adding the params around the entire iterator gives same result (edited OP).